# Not getting Any Events From Asternet.Ari On FreePbx

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, asternet

I have set up FreePbx and it is working I can make calls into the pbx and out of the pbx. I have enabled the REST API and added a user and password. I cloned the Asternet.Ari https://github.com/skrusty/AsterNET.ARI.

The program runs and I get the connected event:

```
            // Create a new Ari Connection
            ActionClient = new AriClient(
                new StasisEndpoint("192.168.1.14", 8088, "userId", "password"),
                "HelloWorld");

            // Hook into required events
            ActionClient.OnStasisStartEvent += c_OnStasisStartEvent;
            ActionClient.OnChannelDtmfReceivedEvent += ActionClientOnChannelDtmfReceivedEvent;
            ActionClient.OnConnectionStateChanged += ActionClientOnConnectionStateChanged;
            ActionClient.OnChannelCallerIdEvent += ActionClient_OnChannelCallerIdEvent;

            ActionClient.Connect();
  ........

    private static void ActionClientOnConnectionStateChanged(object sender)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection state is now {0}", ActionClient.Connected);
    }
```

The ActionClient is connected.
I then call in to a extension but nothing happens. I do not get any other events. Should an event fire when any extension is called? Not sure if I have set the pbx up correctly. I do not get any calling events when I call in from soft phone or from outside Lan on a cell phone.

Comment: So what is actual question? How to debug or what? Use tcpdump, ensure you have permissions in asterisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time have passed but maybe useful yet.
Just set subscribeAllEvents argument to true.

```
        ActionClient = new AriClient(
            new StasisEndpoint("voip", 8088, "root", "password"),
            "HelloWorld",
            true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your Asterisk Ari is connecting, but to get anything in it, you have to create Extension so your call go to Stasis application.

Please edit your extensions.conf file with following information

```
exten => _1XX,1,NoOp()
same => n,Stasis(HelloWorld,PJSIP/${EXTEN}, 45)
same => n,Hangup()
```

This script first check any incoming number which starts with 1 will be forawarded to your ARI script. HelloWorld is name of app so you alread have it in your script. Now any call come it will show whole information on your socket. Now you have to handle this information to any specific task.
\